# replace each character with the first greater character after it

Tags: python, list

I am trying to replace each character with the next greater character after it and if there is no greater character after it then replace it by `'#'`

if I have a circular list of characters `[K, M, Y, R, E, J, A]`
the output should be `[M, Y, #, Y, J, K, K]`

'M is greater than k so replace K with M and Y is greater than M so replace M with Y and so one  ( greater  here means comes after it )'

this is the code that I have tried but it gives wrong output

```
def que1(input_list):
for i in range (len (input_list)-1) :
    j=i+1
    for j in range (len(input_list)-1):
        
     if input_list[i]<input_list[j]:
        input_list[i]=input_list[j]
        
        
     if input_list[i]>input_list[j]:
         input_list[i]='@'

return input_list
```

Comment: What is a "greater" character? Are you going on lexicographic ordering with ASCII?

Comment: @roganjosh greater means comes after it

Comment: @tomjn because the list is circular for example if you are searching for the next greater character for the last element you should start looking from the first element in the list

Comment: "comes after it" is not a strict ordering. That's why I asked if it was lexicographical ordering. You can't talk about programming with "comes after it", it needs to be defined. A computer doesn't know the alphabet, let alone that you're talking about the English alphabet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it :

```
def que1(i_list):
    input_list=i_list*2
    output_list=[]

    for i in range (len (i_list)) :
        found=False
        for j in range (i+1,len(input_list)-1):
            if input_list[i]<input_list[j]:
                output_list.append(input_list[j])
                found=True
                break      
              
        if not found:
            output_list.append('#')

    return output_list
```

output:

```
['M', 'Y', '#', 'Y', 'J', 'K', 'K']
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do what you want.

```
def que1(input_list):
output_list = []

# loop through the input list with index
for index, c in enumerate(input_list):

    # split list at c and create new list
    # [all greater characters after c, all greater character before c]
    tmp = [i for i in input_list[index:] if i > c] + [i for i in input_list[:index] if i > c]

    # if list empty there is no greater character
    if len(tmp) == 0:
        output_list.append('#')
    # else choose the first greater character
    else:
        output_list.append(tmp[0])

return output_list
```

Input: ['K', 'M', 'Y', 'R', 'E', 'J', 'A']

Output: ['M', 'Y', '#', 'Y', 'J', 'K', 'K']

Comment: is the time complexity of this code is O(n^2) ?

Comment: it's actually O(n^3) if I am not mistaken because there are two more loops within the first one

Comment: It should be O(n^2) as the two inner loops only applied to one half of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it.

```
def next_greatest(data):
    out = []
    for idx in range(len(data)):
        char = data[idx]
        cs = iter(data[idx + 1:] + data[:idx])
        while True:
            try:
                curr = next(cs)
            except StopIteration:
                out.append("#")
                break
            if curr > char:
                out.append(curr)
                break
    return out

next_greatest(chars)
>> ['M', 'Y', '#', 'Y', 'J', 'K', 'K']
```